# Laravel 5 on sharing hosting - pages don't work except home page

Tags: .htaccess, server, laravel-5, sharing

I have an issue with setting up my laravel 5.2 app on sharing hosting server.
It works main page, but not any other pages.

my .htaccess file code looks like this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where is might be problem?
What should I do? Any solutions?

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory the same as the one provided with Laravel? Please also check that your host has enabled `mod_rewrite` and set `AllowOverride` to `All`. You can do this by adding random text at the top of either `.htaccess` file - you'll know that is enabled if you receive an *Internal Server Error*.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I find out solution. Problem was PHP version in hosting server. Because Laravel 5 PHP version requirements >=5.5.